# how to display records from database using jsp table

Tags: java, database, spring-mvc

I have a form with two dropdowns, One for selecting a group and the other one for selecting a material so the commandName is DTO class which contains two List fields of "Group" and "Material" classes, i have another class "Absence" mapped ManyToOne to class Student and class Material too, i want to list the students of the selected group to mark their absence in the selected material,also class Absence has a String field which has "present" or "absent" as value and a Date field,how to do that?
Any help on this would be appreciated, Thank you

here is DTO class

```
public class ListeleveDTO {

 private java.util.List<Groupe> groupe;
    private java.util.List<Matiere> matiere;

    public ListeleveDTO() {

    }

    public ListeleveDTO(java.util.List<Groupe> groupe, java.util.List<Matiere> matiere) {

        this.groupe= groupe;
        this.matiere = matiere;


    }
```

Class Absence

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Absence")
public class Absence implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) 
@Column(name="Date", nullable=false)
private Date date;

@Column(name="Etat", unique=true,nullable=false)
private EtatAbs etat;//enum class which contains "Present" or "Absent"


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="Eleve_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private  Eleve eleve;


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="Matiere_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private Matiere matiere;
//getters and setters
```

jsp form

```
 <form:form method="post"  commandName="listeleveDTO" role="form" >

                         <label>Sélectionnez un groupe</label>
                         <select name="Groupe" class="form-control">

                         <option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---" />    


                         <c:forEach items="${listeleveDTO.groupe}" var="m">

                         <option value="${m.libelle}">${m.libelle} </option>                 

                         </c:forEach>

                         </select>



                         <div class="form-group"  style="margin-top:50px">    

                         <label> Sélectionnez une matiere</label>
                         <select name="Matiere" class="form-control">

                         <option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---" />    


                         <c:forEach items="${listeleveDTO.matiere}" var="mg">

                         <option value="${mg.libelle}">${mg.libelle} </option>                 

                         </c:forEach>

                         </select>

                                    </div>               
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-top:30px" >Valider</button>

                                </form:form>
```

Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping ("abs")

@SessionAttributes({"groupe","matiere"})

public class AbsController {


@Autowired GroupeService groupeservice;

@Autowired AbsenceService absenceService;
    @Autowired MatiereService matiereservice;



@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showForm() {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("abs");

    ListeleveDTO listeleveDTO = new ListeleveDTO(groupeservice.findAllGroupes(), matiereservice.findAlmatieres());
    mv.addObject("listeleveDTO",listeleveDTO );

    return mv;
}

@RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitForm( @ModelAttribute("listeleveDTO") ListeleveDTO listeleveDTO,BindingResult result,
        ModelMap map

         ) {

    return "listeleve" ;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/listeleve")
public String geteleves (Model model){

    model.addAttribute("absence", new Absence());
    model.addAttribute("listAbsence", absenceService.findAllAbsence());
    model.addAttribute("etats",EtatAbs.values());
    return "listeleve";
```

}

ListofStudent jsp

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>  
                                        <th width="200px">Eleve</th>
                                        <th width="150px">Absence</th>

                                         <th width="150px">Edit</th>                     
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

                                <sql:query dataSource="${ds}" var="result">
                   SELECT X.FIRST_NAME,X.LAST_NAME,A.Etat,X.id from Absence A, MATIERE M,
                  (SELECT E.id,E.FIRST_NAME,E.LAST_NAME from GROUPE G, ELEVE E where G.LIBELLE= "<%=liste %>" and E.groupe_id = G.id) as X
                   where X.id = A.ELEVE_ID and A.MATIERE_ID = M.id and M.LIBELLE = "<%=liste1%>" ;
                                 </sql:query>


//i joined table groupe and eleve(student) to select first and last name of students then i joined table absence to table matiere (material) and table X the result of joining student and group to select field "etat",this field contains "absent" or "present" student


                                   <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">  
                                   <tr  class="gradeU">

                                   <td><c:out value="${row.FIRST_NAME}"/> <c:out value="${row.LAST_NAME}"/></td>

                                   <td>                   
                                   <c:out value="${row.Etat}"/>
                                   </td>

                                   <td><a href="update.jsp?id=<c:out value="${row.id}"/>"></a></td>
                                   </tr>
                                   </c:forEach>             
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

Comment: Please add some codes and comment what you want. We can't produce code for you.

Comment: @akuma8 i added some codes and commented the sql query part in ListStudent.jsp, i want to change this part of code and working with crud Repository, can you help? thanks

Comment: Spring MVC form tag lib (`form:option`) offers a very kind way to manipulate a list in a form. It will avoid you using a 'foreach' loop in the form. Please check here : https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-dropdown-box-example/
Why using sql taglib inside your jsp ? It's your choice but it seems very ugly

Comment: that's why i m asking about finding another way to do that.

Comment: You have the advantage of using the Spring Framework, so for your form I'll suggest you to use the spring form tag lib which is really convenient for managing List. 
Regaring the persistence layer, as you are using @Entity I will suggest you to use Spring Data Jpa. Your project will be clearer and your jsp pages more readable.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Let me know if you have some trouble.